# What are known portals to the Hells in the Forgotten Realms?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, forgotten-realms, planes, portals

I know that there is (or at least, used to be) one portal in the dungeons under Dragonspear Castle that linked the castle to Avernus, the first level of the Nine Hells. Are there other such fixed portals documented in the Forgotten Realms that connect to the Nine Hells?
(Sources can be from any Edition of D&D, or from other official publications like Dragon Magazine or novels).

Comment: Point of clarification - are you only looking for portals directly from Abeir-Toril in the Material Plane to one of the Nine Hells, or any connection to the Nine Hells from anywhere in the Forgotten Realms cosmology?

Comment: Just to Abeir-Toril. Especially to the Sword Coast, but other areas are also OK.

Comment: @samuei I am fine with the edit in the title to "the Hells", just be aware that as far as I know, there are NO portals to any other layer of the Hells than the first, Avernus. So technically (unless someone comes up with such a protal), there are only portals to a single hell, the first one. With your edit, it's consistent with the body of the question, and maybe such a portal exists...

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin The official name of the plane that Avernus is a part of is 'The Nine Hells', and as such, "The Hells" is simply a truncation of that full name. IMO, The Hells is a more accurate name for the plane than merely 'hell'...as the later is a location in Christian mythology while the former is a place in 5e.

Comment: @aaron9eee Good point, in that case I should have just asked if there is a portal to Avernus. But who knows, maybe somewhere in an adventure someone made a portal to another layer, so in this form the question is not only correct, but also covers that. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- **Fields of the Dead**

According to [Elminster's Candlekeep Companion](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/311436/Elminsters-Candlekeep-Companion) (p46-48):

> the best way to enter Avernus is via the original gate the Hellriders used

and that the hellgate is

> on the Fields of the Dead.

[Descent into Avernus](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/baldurs-gate-descent-into-avernus) also mentions a gate in the Fields of the Dead, but doesn't provide any more specifics.

- **Dragonspear Castle**

> The castle was infamous for the inter-planar portal located in the dungeon beneath its keep. This portal linked the castle to Avernus, the first level of the Nine Hells, allowing passageway for baatezu and other devils into Toril.

- **Myth Drannor**

> A portal to Avernus was erected in the spring of the Year of the Bloodbird, 1346 DR in the Burial Glen of Myth Drannor (...) interference from Malkizid caused it to become permanent. The portal was eventually closed by the Knights of Myth Drannor in 1357 DR (...) [Dragon 359 pp.102-103]